# Is there a way to programmatically set window size to be bigger than display resolution?

Tags: winapi, windows-xp

I have run into a weird necessity to make a certain window in the system of a really big height, one that is larger than my display's resolution. I have written a simple WinAPI program that sets a window size by calling SetWindowPos and I have encountered that if the height is greater than current display's resolution, then it is simply set to be equal to screen height.

This is obviously some Windows trick and I am wondering if there is a way to override that and set an arbitrary size for the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a message handler for WM_MINMAXINFO.

Comment: Didn't know about that message, thanks! 
However, I don't own the application whose window I want to resize, so I handling that message is not a solution here.

Comment: You are making this unreasonably difficult.  SetWindowsHookEx is next.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Are you proposing to set a global hook on WH_CALLWNDPROC?

Comment: That's correct.  You need a DLL so that your code can be injected into the process.